# Bound of $\displaystyle ||\ \cdot\ ||_{H_{1}(\Omega)^{n}}$ with $\displaystyle ||\ \cdot\ ||_{H(div)}$

Tags: numerical-methods, hilbert-spaces, self-learning

I am reading Brenner and Scott's book on finite elements, chapter 12 at the moment. I have come up to something that seems simple, but that I am having trouble figuring out by myself to do with the relationship of different norms.

I have got the spaces

$H^{1}(\Omega)^{n} = \{ w \in L^{2}(\Omega)^{n}\ |\ \partial_{i}w \in L^{2}(\Omega)^{n}\}\\
H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)^{n} = \{ w \in H^{1}(\Omega)^{n}\ |\ w = 0 \text{ for } x \in \partial\Omega\}$

where $\Omega \subset  \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a polygonal domain, and $H^{1}_{0}$ is the subset of $H^{1}$ functions with vanishing trace. I also define

$H(\text{div}) = \{ w \in L^{2}(\Omega)^{n}\ |\ \text{div}(w) \in L^{2}(\Omega). \} $

The corresponding norms are

$\displaystyle || w ||_{L^{2}(\Omega)^{n}} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}||w_{i}||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
\displaystyle || w ||_{H^{1}(\Omega)^{n}} = \left(|| w ||_{L^{2}(\Omega)^{n}}^{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}||\partial_{i}w||_{L^{2}(\Omega)^{n}}^{2}\right)^{1/2} \\
||w||_{H(\text{div})} = \left( ||w||_{L^{2}(\Omega)^{n}}^{2} + ||\text{div}(w)||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}^{2}\right)^{1/2}.$

There is an inequality (Brenner and Scott, pg. 336) which seems very simple, but I can't justify, which is

$\displaystyle \frac{b(w,p)}{||w||_{H^{1}(\Omega)^{n}}} \leq \sqrt{n}\frac{b(w,p)}{||w||_{H(\text{div})}}$

for $w \in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$. Since the only thing that changes in here is the norm, I am now trying to show that

$\displaystyle ||w||_{H^{1}(\Omega)^{n}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}||w||_{H(\text{div})}\tag{1}$

which I can't. I give some more details below, but the inequality (1) is what I am trying to prove

---

I am not sure how to use the fact that $w\in H_{0}^{1}$, and have only gotten so far as to write out the different norms in full. I have that

$$||w||_{H^{1}}^{2} = ||w||_{L^{2}}^{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}||\partial_{i}w||_{L^{2}}^{2} \\
 \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( ||w_{i}||_{L^{2}}^{2} + \sum_{j=1}^{n}||\partial_{i}w_{j}||_{L^{2}}^{2} \right)$$

and

$$||w||_{H(\text{div})}^{2} = ||w||_{L^{2}}^{2} + ||\sum_{i=1}^{n}\partial_{i}w_{i}||_{L^{2}}^{2} \\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}||w_{i}||_{L^{2}}^{2} + \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}||\partial_{i}w_{i}||_{L^{2}}\right)^{2}.$$

I am not sure if this is a good start, as with this direct method of comparison I don't know how to use the fact that $w =0$ on $\partial\Omega$. Any hints as to how I can show inequality (1) would be appreciated

Keeran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is less than meets the eye here. By Cauchy-Schwarz, for any vector $ (v_1,\dots,v_n)$ we have
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\right|^2 \le  n \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2$$
In particular,
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i w_i\right|^2 \le  
n \sum_{i=1}^n (\partial_i w_i)^2 \le n \sum_{i=1}^n \|\partial_i w\|^2$$
Integration yields
$$
\|\mathrm{div}\, w\|_{L^2}^2 \le n 
  \sum_{i=1}^n \|\partial_i w\|_{L^2}^2
$$
Therefore, 
$$
\|w\|_{H(\mathrm{div})}^2  \le n\|w\|_{H^1}^2 
$$
Boundary values of $w$ are irrelevant.

Comment: Yeah, this is a common mistake I make. I keep forgetting about Cauchy-Schwarz for vectors when I am working in function spaces. Thanks for the answer - it is very clear